# Do cargo operators need an AOC?

Tags: aircraft-operations

Is it just commercial operating aircraft flying paying passengers that require an air operators certificate (AOC) or do cargo operators require one also?

Comment: You need an AOC except in very rare circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

An aircraft doesn't need an AOC    Operating the aircraft for anything other than for private purposes is why you need one.

Comment: I think you need a comma in there...